# Python - using (?!...) at the beginning of the re.compile fails

Tags: python

What I'm trying to achieve is searching for the following pattern `XXXxXXX`,
but I don't want something like `XXXXxXXX` or `XXXxXXXX` to match.

When I try the following it just fails to give me an output

```
test = "DDDfSSSsFFFjKKKk"
p = re.compile('(?![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}([a-z]{1})[A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])')
x = p.findall(test)
```

although when I take the beginning of `(?![A-Z])` out it just work fine but it doesn't do the job of avoidng `XXXXxXXX`

```
test = "DDDfSSSsFFFjKKKk"
p = re.compile('[A-Z]{3}([a-z]{1})[A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])')
x = p.findall(test)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a lookbehind assertion, not a lookahead assertion:

```
p = re.compile('(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}(?![A-Z])')
```

Your current regex is saying:

```
(?![A-Z]) # Make sure that the next character isn't an uppercase ASCII letter 
[A-Z]{3}  # Now match three uppercase ASCII letters (<-- impossible>
```

Comment: Thanks alot that has fixed it.